# EC2 Instance created but unable to connect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

using Python3 library `boto3` we created an EC2 instance

```
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=region_name)

def create_instance():
    instances = ec2_client.run_instances(
        ImageId=ami_id,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        InstanceType=instance_type,
        KeyName=key_name
    )
    # print(instances)
    instance_id = instances["Instances"][0]["InstanceId"]
    print(instance_id)

create_instance()
```

The instance got created but we are not able to connect to it.

[image]

Upon the creation of the instance the security group is default.
we think that this might be cause of the following ERROR. What do you guys you think about it?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of the inbound rules in your default security group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical things to check when trying to connect to an EC2 instance:

**Security Groups**
Check that at least one of the Security Groups associated with the instance has port 22 (SSH) or port 3389 (RDP) open to your source IP range. Since you are using **EC2 Instance Connect**, you'll need to open it to the IP range of that service, or just `0.0.0.0/0` (not great for security). Security Groups are stateful, so you only need to open **Inbound** access and the return path will automatically work.

**Public Subnet / Routing**
Confirm that your instance is **in a "Public" VPC Subnet**. This means that the Route Table associated with the Subnet has a route through an Internet Gateway.

**Public IP Address**
Confirm that you are using a **Public IP address** associated with the instance. This can either be assigned at instance launch (which will allocate a random IP address from a pool) or can be assigned as an Elastic IP Address (which is a static IP address that you can assign assign to any instance and you keep it until you release it back to AWS). A Public IP address will be automatically assigned if the instance was launched in a public subnet of the Default VPC.

**AMI Operating System**
I've seen situations where people try to SSH to a Windows instance, or RDP to a Linux instance, so also check that you launched the correct AMI for your expected operating system.

Since you are connecting with EC2 Instance Connect, make sure the instance was launched with Amazon Linux, which has the correct agent software installed.